# Using synonyms in stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a synonym for a table in another DB defined
using

```
create synonym TableA for otherDb.dbo.TableA
```

I have a locally defined stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spGetTableA
AS 
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM TableA
END
```

Now when I call the SP

```
EXEC spGetTableA
```

I get the following error
Invalid object name 'TableA'

While calling the SQL directly `SELECT * FROM TableA`
works perfectly.

Any idea what I'm missing for this to work?

Comment: Don't you need to add the schema to the synonym - `dbo.TableA`?

Comment: adding `dbo.TableA` doesn't change anything :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably calling the stored procedure from a user whose default schema is not dbo. Therefore you should always reference the schema both when you create the synonym and when you reference the table in a query.

```
DROP SYNONYM TableA;
GO
CREATE SYNONYM dbo.TableA FOR OtherDB.dbo.TableA;
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.spGetTableA
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM dbo.TableA;
END
GO
EXEC dbo.spGetTableA;
```

I wish I could bold all of those `dbo.` references within the code. They are important and should ***ALWAYS*** be there.

Please read:

- [Bad habits to kick : avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)